# Relative layout adds all elements on top left corner

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I added a relative layout resource file and whenever I drag and drop an element, it gets set to the top left corner. Any way to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ntpd.jpg

### Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the attribute `android:gravity="center"` to align children inside `RelativeLayout`. This will align children to the center of the layout.
Also, instead of `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, you can use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <!-- you need to align the button to a particular
        place in the layout -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <!-- Then add layout_below/layout_above -->
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_below="@id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch Number 1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also set multiple values : `android:gravity="bottom|right"`. This will align children to bottom right corner.
Last words: learn a lil bit about `RelativeLayout` and how it can be used.
[image]

Comment: It sill doesn't fix my issue. Now, all the items are placed on top of each other in the center instead of the top left.

Comment: @Moataz Updated.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It still had the same issue of just overlaying them on top of each other. I found a solution yesterday or the day before but it almost made the whole "RelativeLayout" view non-existant. Idk what the issue is.

Comment: I have already added a screenshot of the result of code snippet I provided in the answer. If you use the same codes, but the result is different, I guess you're not doing it correctly.